# Accessing app-specific server-side generated files in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a django app (`my_app`) that based on the user query:

1. creates a file from the db
2. runs a program on the file from step-1 and gets an output file
3. generates a json file from the step-2 output file
4. renders a D3 visualization from a django template using the data from the json file from step-3

I need the program to run on the server side and the json file to be generated server-side as well.

Because the json files are query-specific, I thought it's not a good idea to keep these files in the `/static/` folder and thought of keeping the files (even if temporarily) in e.g. `/myapp/output_files/` folder.

The problem is that there is no url pattern corresponding to `/myapp/output_files/my_file.json` and I get a "Page not found (404)" error if I try to open the generated file and it obviously doesn't load in the javascript code in the template.

Is there a better way to design the system? 
If the design is ok, how can I access a json file in the app's folder from the django template? Do I need something in the `urls.py`?

P.S. Everything works fine if I change the json location to `/static/` or its subfolder.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the location to your STATICFILES_DIRS setting as shown [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs)

However, you probably need to build a view function that can somehow return the json based on some parameter in the url. Static files are meant to stay static...

Comment: Thanks @Johan, having a way to keep the files elsewhere and accessing through a `/static/` URL is better than what I had before... it worked! But as you said, static files are meant to stay static. In my case I have not really static files, that's why I think they may be a better way to do all this.